# Fixed points for expanding maps.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Let $X$ be compact and $f:X \to X$ an expanding map. It is well known that $f$ admits a unique fixed point since $f^{-1}$ has to be a contraction. Ok.

Now, consider this: take $U \subset X$ open arbitrary, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^n(U)=X$. In this fashion there is a copy of $f^{-n}(U)$ inside $U$, a copy of $f^{-2n}(U)$ inside $f^{-n}(U)$, and so on.

Take $\bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \left(U \cap f^{-nj}(U)\right)$ so why is not in there a fixed point for $f$?

Edit: It is straightforward that $f$ can not admit two fixed points since it would contradict the definition of expanding, my question is why is that reasoning misleading? Thanks in advance for taking your time to think along. Cheers!

Comment: If the fixed point is not in $U$ then it will not be in $f(U)$ and so there will not be any n such that $f^n(U) = X$.

Comment: @DavidHartley that is not true, imagine you have $2Id$ defined on $\mathbb{T}^2$ so every open set $U$ will eventually satisfy $f^n(U)=\mathbb{T}^2$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: You're right. I was implicitly assuming 1-1.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the inverse, but a expanding map on a compact space is not invertible. If it is surjective, like $2 \times Id$ on $\mathbb{T}^2$, every point has more than one preimage (4, in this case). You can, however, work with pre images. If $U$ is connected and open, $f^{-n}(U)$ has several connected components $V_i$, each one of them satisfying $f(V_i) = U$. Regardless of this, it is not true that there is a connected component of $f^{-n}(U)$ inside $U$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Example: take $f = 2 \times Id: \mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ and let $U = (0.4, 0.6) \times (0.4, 0.6)$. Then $$f^{-1}(U) = (0.2, 0.3) \times (0.2, 0.3) \cup (0.2, 0.3) \times (0.7, 0.8) \cup (0.7, 0.8) \times (0.2, 0.3) \cup (0.7, 0.8) \times (0.7, 0.8),$$

and $f^{-1}(U)$ and $U$ are disjoint.

Comment: For the set you're pointing out, since it is needed to go to $f^3(U)$ to cover the whole $\mathbb{T}^2$ it is not enough to take one preimage, you will need to consider $f^{-3}(U),f^{-6}(U)...$ and so on.

Comment: Nonetheless your answer gives a hint about what $\textit{has}$ to be going on, which is under all certainty that even when the intersection set of the question is non empty, there is no point with its whole orbit inside one of the connected components. But instead more like a shifting of the components inside the set. That is why there is no fixed point. I should check with some manual work but I have a hunch now that this is what really happens.

Comment: If you have to consider $f^{-n}$, $f^{-2n}$, ..., instead of a fixed point, you would get a periodic point.

Comment: But that would lead to the same problem since $f^3$ would be an expanding map with two fixed points.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The point then is to see that $\bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \left(U \cap f^{-nj}(U)\right)$ is either empty ou equal to the fixed point.

Comment: The thing is exactly that! The set is not empty but contains no fixed point!! As I explained above, I'm most certain of what is going on is that the set is not empty (in fact it is a Cantor set) and the map acts as a shift when restricted to the set. That explains it. I should check with more care but I'm positive that is the answer.